# tableau dual axis multiple variables

Tags: tableau-api

Hi I have some insurance data and I am trying to put multiple variables on my map but got stuck. I am using tableau public in my desktop.

To understand what I am plotting, I am interested in if the data is Direct or Agent and if the data is HO3 proudct or BC product. How my data is set up is one column is Direct HO3, another Direct BC, Agent HO3 and another Agent BC. It is broken down by zip with corresponding county.

I tried to use dual axis but with 4 combination first dual layer is Agency (HO3 & BC) and my second dual layer is Direct (HO3 & BC). I need help either putting 4 of these data by using color shelves or hide the second graph as shown. The two charts are the same but I can't get 4 data plotted at the same time. I can't seem to put all 4 columns of data plotted with 1 dual axis chart. All of my data are measures no dimensions except zip code and county column. I do think it has to do with how my raw data is but I am not sure how to modify my raw data so tableau will plot the way I need.

I created hide/un-hide fields to hide data that has 0 HO-3 policy count or 0 BC policy count. Second picture is from my raw data.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your dataset one thought that will work is you can pivot all 4 columns that you are planning to view on the sheet.

Create a chart with pivoted values and then drop the pivoted field name on to the color which will differentiate your measures and show to user

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try and let you know the results.